# start BPM application based on email

Tags: jakarta-mail, jnotify

I am looking for tool/framework that could listen to external event (i.e Email) for my business process management (BPM) application. I know that there are lots of ESB tools out there and It can be useful but I am looking for something tool/framework other than ESB.
for example: 
http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/
or 
Java mail API http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly write a program that uses JavaMail to watch for email of a certain type and then perform some action, but it sounds like you're looking for something more "plug and play".

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest using Jboss Drools which provide Rules and Events APIs.Using the same you can manage various type of Events and depending on the defined rules invoke Business Process